# how to create secret key automatically after 5 minute in C# windows application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I create one function in Class file:

```
public string createprivacykey(string s3)
{
     prky = Convert.ToString(s3);
     return prky;
}
```

and function call in Windows form on button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string clearText = textBox2.Text.Trim();
    string ciphertext=Class1.Encrypt(clearText,true);
    // txtDecryptedText.Visible = false;
    //label3.Visible = false;
    textBox2.Text = ciphertext;

    label3.Visible = true;
    label5.Visible = true;
    label4.Visible = true;

    Random val = new Random();
    int randomnumber1 = val.Next(1001, 50000);
    ra = Convert.ToString(randomnumber1);

    str = cs.createprivacykey(ra);
    label5.Text = str.ToString();
}
```

but i want to key regenerate automatically after 5 minute how to generate key

Comment: A [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Timer would be better option for you

Comment: Why you keep converting your strings to strings? `Convert.ToString(s3)` and `str.ToString()` are all pointless

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to your form using the designer:

- Toolbox - Components - Timer
- Drag the time to your form
- It will appear on the bottom of the designer
- Right Click on it and select properties
- Timer interval: the number of milliseconds in 5 minutes
- Enabled: true if you want it to be enabled as soon as the from is created
- Properties - Events - Tick: the procedure that will be called about every 5 minutes.

Some improvements:

- Fill the time interval in the constructor: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).ToMilliSeconds;
- Enable the timer when the form is shown. This case you're guaranteed that your form is initialized the first time your timer ticks.